# Dividing dimensions to get a count

Tags: tex-core, counters, calculations, dimensions

Is there a way to divide two `dimen`s and get a `count`?  For example, if I have a box that doesn't fit on a single page, and I want to know the number of pages I'd need for the box (i.e., `\heightofbox / \textheight`), can I get that in a count, or in a macro without any trailing units?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calculations can be done with e-TeX's `\dimexpr` or `\numexpr`. In the following example, the first expression in `\typeout` calculates a real number, in the second expression the result is an integer number, rounded up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newsavebox{\mybox}

\begin{document}
  \sbox\mybox{\rule{1pt}{3000pt}}
  \makeatletter
  \typeout{\strip@pt\dimexpr 1pt * \ht\mybox / \textheight\relax}
  \typeout{\the\numexpr(\ht\mybox + \textheight/2)/\textheight\relax}
  \makeatother
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
5.45454
6
```

Remarks:

- In a numerical context (e-)TeX treats dimen or length registers as numbers with unit `sp` (`1pt` = `65536sp`).
- `\strip@pt` removes the unit `pt` from the result of `\dimexpr`.
- The e-TeX `\...expr` commands round the result. In your case you probably want ceiling. This is achieved by adding the half of the divisor.
- The expressions are expandable, thus it is easy to use them in counter assignments or inside `\edef`.

**But** these numbers should be taken with care:

- If the box contains something large, that is not breakable, then result would be an overfull `\vbox` instead of the calculated pages, reducing the count of pages.
- The box might contain stretchable glue that might occupy more space than calculated with
  the natural box height. There can be more pages than calculated.

For a more accurate calculation, the box could be split using `\vsplit` to get the number of pages needed. Depending on the application the number of pages could also be calculated by using page references.

Answer (score 13):

You can directly truncate the division by the trick `\counter=\length` trick which would multiply the length (in `pt`) by 65536 to get an integer number of `sp` units (which egreg taught me). Then you can divide and obtain a truncated result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\mycounterA
\newcount\mycounterB

\mycounterA=\textheight\relax
\mycounterB=\dimexpr100cm\relax

\begin{document}

\the\mycounterA\par
\the\mycounterB\par

The result is : \divide\mycounterB by\mycounterA\the\mycounterB\par
\advance\mycounterB by 1%
Pages needed : \the\mycounterB

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One big problem is that you will get 6 pages also if the length to be divided fits *exactly* on 5 pages. So I would subtract 1 from `\mycounterB` before dividing.

Comment: @StephanLehmke Subtracting 1 *is* the right thing to do. Of course, the chances that the division is exact are minuscule, but it can happen.

Answer (score 3):

The [`fp` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) can manage floating point operations, while `\strip@pt` is a core-macro that strips the dimension from a length. Here's a small example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\newlength{\lengthA}\newlength{\lengthB}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\lengthA}{20em}
\verb|\lengthA: |\the\lengthA \par
\setlength{\lengthB}{5em}
\verb|\lengthB: |\the\lengthB \par
\bigskip

\makeatletter
\edef\valueA{\strip@pt\lengthA}
\edef\valueB{\strip@pt\lengthB}
\FPeval\result{\valueA/\valueB}
\verb|\lengthA/\lengthB: |\result
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the dimensions to counters, wheras their division results to an truncated integer, but a simple division will give you problematic results. The division is: How often does *q* (`\textwidth`) go in *p* (`\heightoftext`)?
The mathematical formula would be `ceil(p/q)` (rounding up). As *p* and *q* are integer values (counters in TeX) we can implement the ceiling function with a little trick.
Let’s take a look at *q* = 4, *p* = 2, …, 9:

```
       p             │  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  │
─────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────
  int( p    / q)     │  2  2  1  1  1  1  0  │  what we get
 ceil( p    / q)     │  3  2  2  2  2  1  1  │  what we want
  int( p    / q) + 1 │  3  3  2  2  2  2  1  │  what works for p/q ≠ int(p/q)
  int((p–1) / q) + 1 │  3  2  2  2  2  1  1  │  = ceil(p/q)
```

The second last row needs to be shifted by one to get the actual ceiling function what we achieve by subtracting `1` from *q*.

```
\def\divideMeCount#1#2{%
    \countp=#1\relax%
    \advance\countp by -1\relax%
    \countq=#2\relax%
    \divide\countp by \countq\relax%
}
```

---

Another solution uses a loop effectively counting the pages:

```
\def\divideMeLoop#1#2{%
    \dimenp=#1\relax%
    \dimenq=#2\relax%
    \tempi=0\relax%
    \loop\advance\dimenp by -\dimenq\relax\advance\tempi by 1\relax%
    \ifdim\dimenp>0pt\relax\repeat%
}
```

#### Values

- `\textheight = 550.0pt`
- `\heightofbox =`

  - `1099pt`
  - `1100pt`
  - `1101pt`

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcount\countp
\newcount\countq
\newdimen\dimenp
\newdimen\dimenq
\newcount\tempi
\newdimen\heightofbox
\def\divideMeCount#1#2{%
    \countp=#1\relax%
    \advance\countp by -1\relax%
    \countq=#2\relax%
    \divide\countp by \countq\relax%
}
\def\divideMeLoop#1#2{%
    \dimenp=#1\relax%
    \dimenq=#2\relax%
    \tempi=0\relax%
    \loop\advance\dimenp by -\dimenq\relax\advance\tempi by 1\relax%
    \ifdim\dimenp>0pt\relax\repeat%
}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\heightofbox=1099pt\relax
\the\heightofbox/\the\textheight\par
{\bfseries Counters\par}
\divideMeCount{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
counpt+1=\number\numexpr\countp+1\relax\par
{\bfseries Dimensions (Loop)\par}
\divideMeLoop{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
tempi=\the\tempi\par
{\bfseries PGF (example)\par}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{ceil(\heightofbox/\textheight)}
result=\result
\bigskip

\heightofbox=1100pt\relax
\the\heightofbox/\the\textheight\par
{\bfseries Counters\par}
\divideMeCount{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
counpt+1=\number\numexpr\countp+1\relax\par
{\bfseries Dimensions (Loop)\par}
\divideMeLoop{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
tempi=\the\tempi\par
{\bfseries PGF (example)\par}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{ceil(\heightofbox/\textheight)}
result=\result
\bigskip

\heightofbox=1101pt\relax
\the\heightofbox/\the\textheight\par
{\bfseries Counters\par}
\divideMeCount{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
counpt+1=\number\numexpr\countp+1\relax\par
{\bfseries Dimensions (Loop)\par}
\divideMeLoop{\heightofbox}{\textheight}
tempi=\the\tempi\par
{\bfseries PGF (example)\par}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\result}{ceil(\heightofbox/\textheight)}
result=\result
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @StephanLehmke Yes, it is easier. I haven’t thought of that. Apparently, the error of that calculation is smaller than the actual dimension precision.

Comment: I think your explanation of the correction by subtracting 1 is wrong (or at least misleading). You want to know how many chunks of size *c* you need to contain a quantity *q*. And you want to calculate this with the formula *q/c+1*. This is simply wrong, because the result is off by 1 if *q* is a multiple of *c*.

Comment: @StephanLehmke What I would have done initially is `q/c + 1` if `q/c ≠ int(q/c)`, `q/c` otherwise (because the result of a counter division `q/c` will be floored); this is what I have expressed also in the PGF formula, as we actually want to calculate `ceil(q/c)`. I didn’t want to express these conditions in TeX, so I used the looping method. What we do now is `(65536 q - 1)/(65536 c)`, hardly more correct (mathematically)‽

Comment: No the counters are the exact lengths (expressed in `sp`), so the calculation is correct. It's an illusion that lengths are somewhat "continuous" in TeX, a length register is the same as a count register just with a different "API".

Comment: @StephanLehmke Be that as it may. I still need to add `1` to the result because my division’s result will be truncated. But I would agree that there’s no error.