# Is there a pre-defined width that covers the text area and the margin?

Tags: lengths

Is there a pre-defined width that covers both the text and margin areas? Correct me if I am wrong, but it would basically be equal to `\textwidth+\marginparsep+\parginparwidth`.

Is that provided by LaTeX somewhere?

If not, I am currently defining it this way in the preamble:

```
\newlength{\widewidth}
\setlength{\widewidth}{\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
```

Is that the right approach? Are there any caveats? For example, if I change a page's orientation, would `\widelength` change its size to reflect that?

Comment: Have you tried \linewidth?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, `\linewidth` is the same as `\textwidth`. Should that not have been the case?

Comment: @sudosensei I haven't confirmed it, but I seem to recall that `\linewidth` and `\textwidth` are the same in the default configuration, but if you change the page's orientation, `\textwidth` does not change, but `\linewidth` does account for the revised orientation.  Also, keep in mind that the `\marginpar` can be changed from the one side of the page to the other.  While the overall width may stay the same, the beginning/ending locations on the paper will change.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for the explanation, Steven. The beginning and ending positions are decided by the `figure*` environment (from the `sidenotes` package) that places figures across the margin and text block. The length I am defining is only a convenience variable, really, so that I can say `\includegraphics[width=\widewidth]` - `\textwidth` and `linewidth` are the same as outside the `figure*` environment. I guess the question is whether this is the right way to define the length, assuming that starting/ending points have ben taken care of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a user length is defined, it is fixed in physical units until reset by the user (see [Defining a Length that Scales with Fontsize Changes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/defining-a-length-that-scales-with-fontsize-changes)).  So the way you define a "length" that can adjust with page dimension changes is to define it as a macro `\def` in terms of the system lengths that are updated with format changes, rather than as a `\setlength` which will fix the length.  In this manner, the `\def` is re-evaluated to its "current" value at every invocation.

Once that lesson is learned, the next aspect to your question is that `\linewidth` rather than `\textwidth` is the appropriate length to use when, for example, changing into landscape mode, etc.  On page 1 of my MWE, it makes no difference which is used, but on page 2, one can see that the `\linewidth` definition gives the proper result, not the `\textwidth` result.

And finally, if `\reversemarginpar` is used, as is done on page 3 of the MWE, then extra provisions must be made

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
  \def\wrongwidewidth{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}%
  \def\rightwidewidth{\dimexpr\linewidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{This is a test of a margin par}\vspace{2cm}\par
Doesn't matter\par
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\wrongwidewidth]{test}

Doesn't matter\par
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\rightwidewidth]{test}
\begin{landscape}
  \lipsum[2]\marginpar{This is a test of a margin par}\vspace{2cm}\par
  Wrong\par
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\wrongwidewidth]{test}

  Right\par
  \noindent\includegraphics[width=\rightwidewidth]{test}
\end{landscape}

With reverse marginpar, tricks must be done\vspace{2cm}\par\reversemarginpar
\lipsum[1]\marginpar{This is a test of a margin par}\vspace{2cm}\par
Doesn't matter\par
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\includegraphics[width=\wrongwidewidth]{test}}

Doesn't matter\par
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][r]{\includegraphics[width=\rightwidewidth]{test}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very well explained. I wasn't aware of the difference between `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`. Thank you, Steven!