# Write a class with different code for different version

Tags: macros, documentclass-writing

I want to write a report-like class (maybe based on KOMA-Script). 
My problem is that the layout will be evolving and maybe the features of the package to. I would like to know if there is an easy way of writing a package that is backward compatible. For instance that has different macro definitions for different versions of the package.

**EDIT**

More specifically, I would like to know if there is already a package that can help/support this task:

- Some way to define the current version of the class.
- A way to check the version of the document.

Comment: This question is a little bit broad, in my point of view. I would advise to use an option interface to the package/class file such that it is configured depending on the state of the options

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I look for a package that has macros to handle this kind of options, or somewhere to see "standard" ways of programming this things.

Comment: I have answered recently a 'similar' question, perhaps my answer provides some clue/hint how to proceed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224405/how-to-change-theorem-numbering-when-macro-file-is-involved. `xkeyval` is just one possibility

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the link. I found a similar one here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215872/package-versioning-and-backward-compatibility)

Comment: Are there any news here? Maybe you can provide a self answer?