# How to link 2 lengths

Tags: lengths

I would really like to create a length `\bar` that defaults to having the same as the length `\foo` even if `\foo` gets changed, but I would also like the user to be able to set `\bar` to be whatever length they want. I can get close if instead of a length `\bar` I use a macro `\baz`, but the user would need to be careful with the usage. What is the best way to go about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\bar\relax
\newlength{\foo}
\newlength{\bar}\setlength{\bar}{\foo}
\newlength{\qux}
\def\baz{\foo}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\foo}{100pt}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \the\baz\par

\setlength{\foo}{2\baz}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \the\baz\par

\def\baz{400pt}
\setlength{\qux}{2\baz}\bigskip
% Note that \baz no long works with \the
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \baz\par
% Note that \qux is "wrong"
qux: \the\qux\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: For one thing, since `\baz` is a string, not a length, use  `\setlength{\qux}{2\dimexpr\baz}`

Comment: This is something similar to what `xassoccnt` does for counters, I think

Comment: Related maybe? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/defining-a-length-that-scales-with-fontsize-changes

Comment: You could also define `\def\baz{\dimexpr\foo}` if you always wanted `\baz` to behave like a length, but change as `\foo` changes.  This is unlike `\bar`, which is fixed with the `\setlength`, regardless of how `\foo` subsequently changes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes the problem with `\dimexpr` is it loses any strecthable glue.

Comment: See the edit of my answer as to how glue can be incorporated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a similar approach that I used in my `xassoccnt` package for counters: associating a length to a 'master' length, say '\foo'.

If `\foo` is assigned a new value with `\setlength`, all lengths associated with it will get the same value.

I defined `\addtolength` etc, as well as removal and synchronization.
The starred version of `\setlength` and `\addtolength` will manipulate the master length only!

However, a direct manipulation of `\foo` will not work for `\baz` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@setlength\setlength
\let\latex@addtolength\addtolength

\newcommand{\stripslash}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@gobble\string#1
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \strongbad_associate_lengths:nn {%
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn {g_strongbad_#1_lengths_seq} {#2} % Populate unexpanded
  \seq_remove_duplicates:c {g_strongbad_#1_lengths_seq}
  \seq_remove_all:cn {g_strongbad_#1_lengths_seq} {#1}% Prevent self - association!
  \seq_map_inline:cn {g_strongbad_#1_lengths_seq} {
    \dim_if_exist:NF { ##1 } {% Preventing complaining about already existing length variables
      \newlength{##1}
    }
  }
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\RemoveAssociatedLengths}{mm}{%
  \seq_if_exist:cT { g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#1} _lengths_seq } {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
      \seq_remove_all:cn { g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#1} _lengths_seq } {##1}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareAssociatedLength}{mm}{%
  \strongbad_add_associated_length:nn {#1}{#2}
}

\cs_new:Nn \strongbad_add_associated_length:nn {%
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g_strongbad_\stripslash{#1}_lengths_seq} {
    \seq_new:c {g_strongbad_\stripslash{#1}_lengths_seq}
  }
  \strongbad_associate_lengths:nn{\stripslash{#1}}{#2}
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\AddAssociatedLengths}{mm}{%
  \strongbad_associate_lengths:nn{\stripslash{#1}}{#2}  
}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\addtolength}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{% No starred command
    \seq_if_exist:cT { g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#2} _lengths_seq } {
      \seq_map_inline:cn {  g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#2} _lengths_seq } {
        \latex@addtolength{##1}{#3}
      }% End of \seq_map_inline
    }% End of \seq_if_exist
  }% End of \IfBooleanF
  \latex@addtolength{#2}{#3}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\synclengths}{m}{%
  \seq_if_exist:cT { g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#1} _lengths_seq } {
    \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim {\the#1}
    \setlength{#1}{\l_tmpa_dim}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\syncaddtolength}{mm}{%
  \addtolength*{#1}{#2}%
  \synclengths{#1}%
}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\setlength}{smm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{% No starred command
    \seq_if_exist:cT { g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#2} _lengths_seq } {
      \seq_map_inline:cn {  g_strongbad_ \stripslash{#2} _lengths_seq } {
        \latex@setlength{##1}{#3}
      }% End of \seq_map_inline
    }% End of \seq_if_exist
  }% End of \IfBooleanF
  \latex@setlength{#2}{#3}
}

\makeatother


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newlength{\foo}

\newlength{\boz}

\DeclareAssociatedLength{\foo}{\baz,\buz,\boz,\biz}

\setlength{\foo}{100pt}


foo: \the\foo

baz: \the\baz

buz: \the\buz

boz: \the\boz

biz: \the\biz

\setlength{\baz}{\dimexpr200pt+\foo}

Foo again: \the\foo

Baz now: \the\baz

buz: \the\buz

boz: \the\boz

biz: \the\biz

Now using the starred version:

\setlength*{\foo}{5000pt}

Foo after starred version: \the\foo

Baz after starred version: \the\baz


Adding some value:

\addtolength{\foo}{100pt}

Foo after adding some value: \the\foo

Baz after adding some value to foo: \the\baz


Adding some value with synchronization first:

\syncaddtolength{\foo}{100pt}

Foo after adding some value: \the\foo

Baz after adding some value to foo: \the\baz

Buz after adding some value to foo: \the\buz

Removing buz and biz:

\RemoveAssociatedLengths{\foo}{\buz,\biz}

\addtolength{\foo}{-1000pt}

New foo: \the\foo

New biz: \the\biz

New buz: \the\buz



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is `\cs_to_str:N`. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Really? Well, I reinvented the wheel then...

Answer (score 3):

`\baz` expands to `\foo`, which is a length, and therefore `2\baz` works in the second length setting. However, letting `\def\baz{400pt}` doesn't make `\baz` a length anymore. Yes, technically it expands to a valid length, but it can't be used as-is in a length product. You'll have to explicitly use `\dimexpr`, otherwise the values are concatenated rather than multiplied:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\bar\relax% Just for this example

\newlength{\foo}% \foo is a length
\newlength{\bar}\setlength{\bar}{\foo}% \bar is a length
\newlength{\qux}% \qux is a length
\def\baz{\foo}% \baz expands to \foo, which is a length

\begin{document}

\setlength{\foo}{100pt}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \the\baz\par

\setlength{\foo}{2\baz}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \the\baz\par

\def\baz{400pt}% \baz is no longer a length
\setlength{\qux}{2\dimexpr\baz}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par bar: \the\bar\par baz: \the\dimexpr\baz\par
qux: \the\qux\par

\end{document}
```

On the somewhat sly side, you could

```
\def\baz{\dimexpr400pt}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create linked lengths, but you need different commands (or to override the standard ones). The syntax is similar to `\newcounter`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewLength}{mo}
 {
  \newlength{#1}
  \seq_new:c { g_strongbad_length_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
  \IfValueT{#2}
   {
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_strongbad_length_ \cs_to_str:N #2 _seq } { #1 }
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetLength}{mm}
 {
  \setlength{#1}{#2}
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g_strongbad_length_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
   {
    \setlength{##1}{#2}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewLength{\foo}
\NewLength{\baz}[\foo]
\NewLength{\qux}

\begin{document}

\SetLength{\foo}{100pt}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par baz: \the\baz\par

\SetLength{\foo}{2\baz}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par baz: \the\baz\par

\SetLength{\baz}{10pt}\bigskip
foo: \the\foo\par baz: \the\baz\par

\SetLength\baz{400pt}
\SetLength{\qux}{2\baz}\bigskip
qux: \the\qux\par

\end{document}
```

Every defined length has an associated list of lengths, which are set to the same value as the master length as soon as this is modified (with `\SetLength`). I leave to you as an exercise to implement `\AddToLength`.

[image]

Comment: Ah.... I was a little bit faster than you, having the same idea ;-)

Comment: Any chance that `\SetLength\baz{400pt}` could "break" the association such that a future `\SetLength{\foo}{100pt}` would not change `\baz`?

Comment: @StrongBad That's a very different thing. It can be done, but I can't see what's the use of it. By the way, the assignments respect groups.

Comment: I have an image/logo that should default to `\textwidth` (maybe `\linewidth`),  but if the user really wants it to be 6cm, then I don't want changes to `\textwidth` to interfere.

Comment: @StrongBad `\textwidth` shouldn't change in the document. This seems to be an XY-question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say I want a length that is double `\foo` minus 3 pt.  Using a length to define it (as in the case of `\barr`), it is fixed at the time of definition, so that subsequent changes in `\foo` have no influence on `\barr`.

However, using a `\def` that begins with `\dimexpr` (as in the case of `\baz`) allows `\foo` and `\baz` to be eternally linked into the x2 - 3pt relationship, even as `\foo` changes.  Furthermore, `\baz` acts like a length, even though it is not, so that `\the\dimexpr3\baz` yields the expected length result.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\foo
\newlength\barr
\setlength\foo{100pt}
\setlength\barr{\dimexpr2\foo-3pt}
\def\baz{\dimexpr2\foo-3pt\relax}
\begin{document}
\the\foo, \the\barr, \the\baz

\setlength\foo{200pt}
\the\foo, \the\barr, \the\baz

\the\dimexpr3\baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

**FOLLOW UP**

The question arose on how this `\dimexpr` approach can handle glue.  The answer is yes it can, if `\relax` is used to terminate the `\dimexpr` *before* the glue is added.  Thus,

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\foo
\setlength\foo{100pt}
\def\baz{\dimexpr2\foo-3pt\relax minus20pt}
\begin{document}

\foo=100pt\relax

x\hspace{\baz}x

x\hspace{197pt minus 20pt}x

x\hspace{197pt}x

\noindent\hrulefill

\foo=165pt\relax

x\hspace{\baz}x

x\hspace{327pt minus 20pt}x

x\hspace{327pt}x

\end{document}
```

[image]

As can be seen, the glue is operational in the expansion of `\baz`.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `\glueexpr` might be better than `\dimexpr`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr

Comment: @StrongBad Thanks for the link.  I really had no familiarity with `\glueexpr`.  Whether it makes sense for your application depends on whether you want the glue to scale with multiplication or not.  So indeed, one could use `\def\baz{\glueexpr\dimexpr2\foo-3pt\relax minus 20pt\relax}`