# \parskip, and \parindent

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

This is a bit of a strange one, but I want to be able to base the values of `parskip` and `\parindent` on the other (so I can change one and it will change both). I have a way of making them both the same:

`\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
 \setlength{\parindent}{\parskip}`

But that looks a bit odd. I want to be able to make `\parindent` a multiple of `\parskip`. I tried something like:

`\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
 \setlength{\parindent}{2*\parskip}`

But that didn't work.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: It should be `2\parskip`; but are you really sure you want both paragraph spacing *and* indent?

Comment: Ah. Thanks, I thought it would be easy. And yes :)

Comment: why would you want the vertical (and stretchy) parskip value to be the same as the horizontal and not stretchy parindent (or ever have both of them non-zero)?

Comment: Note that lengths, unlike `\def`s, are set at the time of definition, not at the time of invocation.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/defining-a-length-that-scales-with-fontsize-changes