# How to declare "newcommand" value as a sum of some number (with units) and another command so that it can be used in coordinate arithmetic?

Tags: macros, margins, calculations

I suspect that arithmetic I put inside `newcommand` is not processed as I would expect.

What is the value of `\FMARGIN` after declaring it as

```
\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}
```

Is it 12mm or something else?

Because when I use it inside coordinate arithmetic I get unexpected results. Not all margins are same distance away from the bounding box.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {%
        calc,
        shapes.geometric
    }
\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                draw=blue,
                minimum width=30mm,
                line width=1mm
            ]   {};
        \path
            [%
                draw=red,
                line width=1mm
            ]
            ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\FMARGIN,\FMARGIN)$)
            rectangle
            ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\FMARGIN,-\FMARGIN)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Difference becomes more obvious when `\FWIDTH` is set to a higher value (like 5mm).

Comment: Try using package `calc` and then use `\newlength\FMARGIN \setlength\FMARGIN{2mm} ... \setlength\FBWIDTH{10mm+\FMARGIN}` or whatever. Or use the PGF maths stuff `\pgfmathsetlength ...` or even `\pgfmathsetmacro ...`. But PGF maths is slow.

Comment: I would answer, probably, but the question is 'what does it give?' and @ShreevatsaR already answered that. I'm somewhat surprised you don't get an error.

Comment: Note that you can always use `\show\FMARGIN` to find out for yourself.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR You should answer, since you actually answered the question and I can't fit my non-answer into a comment.

Comment: `\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{\dimexpr10mm+\FWIDTH\relax}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What was originally used in the question, namely

```
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}
```

stores as `\FMARGIN` the tokens in the command.  Substitution and evaluation is not made until it is used.  However, when TeX is looking for a length, something like `10mm+2mm` will not do.  Rather, the command `\dimexpr10mm+2mm\relax` is needed to perform the addition of lengths and provide the result as a single length which can be used by the macro seeking a length input.

`\dimexpr` stands for "dimensional expression" (the dimension being length) and `\relax` terminates the evaluation of a dimensional expression.

If one needs the result in textual form, that is, the tokens that are equivalent to a length of `12mm`, then one uses `\the\dimexpr10mm+2mm\relax`, whereas without the `\the`, the result is stored as an internal length and not a series of alphanumeric tokens.

A good way to see what is happening is comparing this code:

```
\edef\tmp{10mm+\FWIDTH}
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}
```

to this code

```
\edef\tmp{\the\dimexpr10mm+\FWIDTH\relax}
\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}
```

The former evaluates to `10mm+2mm` while the latter evaluates to `34.14328pt`.  Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
    {%
        calc,
        shapes.geometric
    }
\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{\dimexpr10mm+\FWIDTH\relax}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \path node
            [%
                isosceles triangle,
                draw=blue,
                minimum width=30mm,
                line width=1mm
            ]   {};
        \path
            [%
                draw=red,
                line width=1mm
            ]
            ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\FMARGIN,\FMARGIN)$)
            rectangle
            ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\FMARGIN,-\FMARGIN)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

When defining macros (such as with `\newcommand`), TeX does no arithmetic: you can think of it as simple substitution of strings (or to be more precise, tokens). So when you write:

```
\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}
```

no arithmetic happens in `10mm+\FWIDTH`. The result is that `\FMARGIN` gets defined as a macro which expands to `10mm+\FWIDTH` (and this has no special arithmetical meaning; it's simply a sequence of five tokens `1`, `0`, `m`, `m`, `+`, followed by the token `\FWIDTH`). And when you use it somewhere as `\FMARGIN`, under typical circumstances it will (ultimately) expand to the string `10mm+2mm`, which again is simply a sequence of 8 characters: it's as if you had typed `10mm+2mm` at that place.

So when you use:

```
        ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\FMARGIN,\FMARGIN)$)
        rectangle
        ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\FMARGIN,-\FMARGIN)$);
```

it's as if you had typed

```
        ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-10mm+2mm,10mm+2mm)$)
        rectangle
        ($(current bounding box.south east)+(10mm+2mm,-10mm+2mm)$);
```

and although this happens to compile, it is clearly not what you want. Macros work this way because TeX was initially designed for typesetting, and macros were supposed to be a shortcut for saving typing, not for doing computation.

You can debug this for yourself (see what has `\FMARGIN` been defined as) by adding `\show\FMARGIN`) into the file:

```
\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}
\show\FMARGIN
```

when TeX reaches that point, it will show you the expansion and wait for you to hit Return before continuing:

```
> \FMARGIN=\long macro:
->10mm+\FWIDTH .
l.10 \show\FMARGIN

?
```

Reading this requires some training, but what the above tells you is that `\FMARGIN` is defined as `10mm+\FWIDTH` (not as `12mm`).

So how do you fix this? In this case, because `mm` is a dimension that TeX happens to understand (but only when it's *looking* for a length, not when simply defining macros and such), there are some tricks you can use:

- you can define `\FMARGIN` as a *length*, using `\setlength`, as in [@cfr's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390176/how-to-make-newcommand-value-a-sum-of-some-number-with-units-and-another-com/#390184)
- you can define `\FMARGIN` to expand to something that will result in `12mm` when TeX is looking for a length, as in [@Steven's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390176/how-to-make-newcommand-value-a-sum-of-some-number-with-units-and-another-com/#390185)
- you can implement your original intention of somehow defining `\FMARGIN` to expand to `12mm`, though it is slightly tricky (again, see Steven's answer).

Answer (score 5):

This isn't an answer, but too long for a comment. It doesn't answer the question asked, that is. It does address a potential follow-up of how to avoid the problem.

Macros expand to their replacement text. For handling dimensions, it is easiest to use dimensions/lengths. For handling integers, it is easiest to use counts/counters.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric}
\newlength\FMARGIN
\newlength\FWIDTH
\tikzset{%
  fwidth/.code={\setlength\FWIDTH{#1}},
  fmargin/.code={\setlength\FMARGIN{10mm+#1}},
  fwidth/.forward to=/tikz/fmargin,
  fwidth=2mm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path node [isosceles triangle, draw=blue, minimum width=30mm, line width=1mm ]   {};
  \path [draw=red, line width=1mm ] ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\FMARGIN,\FMARGIN)$) rectangle ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\FMARGIN,-\FMARGIN)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[fwidth=20mm]
  \path node [isosceles triangle, draw=blue, minimum width=30mm, line width=1mm ]   {};
  \path [draw=red, line width=1mm ] ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-\FMARGIN,\FMARGIN)$) rectangle ($(current bounding box.south east)+(\FMARGIN,-\FMARGIN)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: variable margins]

Comment: I noticed both of these triangles are still a little (few pixels) off margin at the apex. Which means there is something else to consider. But it's a minor issue in comparison with what I had before. Using \setlength works (although not perfectly). It may be that the bounding box behaving not as expected.

Comment: @bp2017 The maths is not very precise in Ti*k*Z. Are you sure it is not just the expected level of imprecision?

Answer (score 3):

I found `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` to be the easiest solution.

All I did was replace `\newcommand` in

`\newcommand{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\newcommand{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}`

with `\pgfmathsetlengthmacro` to get

`\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\FWIDTH}{2mm}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\FMARGIN}{10mm+\FWIDTH}`

Now coordinate arithmetic calculates `\FMARGIN` correctly.

Comment: You should be aware, if not already, of one additional distinction between a "length" and a "macro".  A length, once set, is fixed, whereas a macro is evaluated at time of use.  Thus, as a length, `\FMARGIN` will be locked in at 12mm, even if `\FWIDTH` later changes.  As a `\newcommand` macro, `\FMARGIN` will change automatically, in the event that `\FWIDTH` is changed.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123443/defining-a-length-that-scales-with-fontsize-changes