# Why are my dimension calculations so far off?

Tags: e-tex, dimension-expressions

I've got some macros storing information about various dimensions.  When I start dividing by dimensions, though, I'm getting answers that don't make sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\def\aetopmargin{0.85in}%%
\def\aebotmargin{0.5in}%%
\def\aeworkspacetopsep{4ex}
\def\aeworkspacerulesep{0.65cm}
\edef\aeworkspaceheight{\dimexpr\paperheight-\aeworkspacetopsep-\aetopmargin-\aebotmargin}
\typeout{==>Work space height===>\strip@pt\dimexpr\aeworkspaceheight}
\typeout{==>Work space rule: ===>\strip@pt\dimexpr\aeworkspacerulesep}
\typeout{==>Their quotient is===>\strip@pt\dimexpr \dimexpr\aeworkspaceheight\relax / \dimexpr\aeworkspacerulesep\relax \relax}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
empty
\end{document}
```

When I run this I get the following output on the terminal:

```
==>Work space height===>499.5079
==>Work space rule: ===>18.49411
==>Their quotient is===>0.00041
```

Shouldn't I be getting something more like

```
==>Their quotient is===>27.00902...
```

Comment: Nevermind now I got what you mean. Sorry

Comment: rather than defining a macro, try using `\newdimen\xxx \setdimen\xxx0.85in` etc.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I could do that, but it's actually easier for the current document if I don't have to work with dimensions for these values.  On the surface, I'm sure that sounds absurd.  But I designed the document around the macros because for the most part I'm actually not using these as dimensions.

Comment: `pgfmath` reports the correct values so it must be an ambiguous interpretation of `etex`

Comment: @percusse I just tried `pgfmath` (because you mentioned it) and it gave me an "Arithmetic overflow" error.  This is what I fed it: `\pgfmathparse{\aeworkspaceheight/\aeworkspacerulesep}`

Comment: @percusse When I write `\pgfmathparse{\dimexpr\aeworkspaceheight\relax/\dimexpr\aeworkspacerulesep\relax}` I get the same erroneous `0.00041`

Comment: It needs parenthesis around them *to your previous comment* :)

Comment: @percusse.  OK that works.  But why does `\pgfmathparse{\dimexpr\aeworkspaceheight\relax/\dimexpr\aeworkspacerulesep\rela‌​x}` still not work correctly?

Comment: If we find it out that would be the answer to your question too :) I think it terminates parsing the whole number for some reason. And I'm out of votes :|

Comment: @percusse  Fortunately this is all coming up in a context where I'm perfectly happy using `pgfmath`.  So I've got a solution, but not an answer.  :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only divide by a length  *number* , returning a length using etex `/` you can not divide two lengths to get a number. So if you divide by a length it is cast to a number by taking the length as an integer number of `sp` that number is a lot bigger than you intended, so the quotient is rather small.

Comment: What you say makes sense.  Originally, I was trying to follow the suggestion made by @HeikoOberdiek at [Dividing dimensions to get a count](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85756/22413)

Comment: @A.Ellett the first bullet point in Heiko's answer there is essentially this answer.

Comment: That's why I got confused. I thought I was being faithful to his answer.  His calculations look like they're being done the same as mine, but his come out correct.

Comment: @A.Ellett Heiko's code tends to have that characteristic:-)

Comment: @A.Ellett in his example `\dimexpr 1pt * \ht\mybox / \textheight\relax` he introduces the 2^16 sp scale factor on top and bottom of the quotient a `*\ht\mybox` takes the height in sp as a number and `/ \textheight` takes `\textheight` in sp so it cancels out, but you only had one sp length.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment.  That's what I was failing to understand.